# Does IF perform better than IF-ELSE?

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement

Which one of these blocks of code performs better, and which one of them is more readable?
I'd guess the gain would be negligible, particularly in the second block. I am just curious.

**Block #1**

```
string height;
string width;
if (myFlag == 1)
{
    height = "60%";
    width = "60%";
}
else
{
    height = "80%";
    width = "80%";
}
```

**Block #2**

```
string height = "80%";
string width = "80%";
if (myFlag == 1)
{
    height = "60%";
    width = "60%";
}
```

---

**Updated**

The results when i tested the above code were that both the blocks performed the same

**Block #1**

```
myFlag = 1:   3 Milliseconds
myFlag = 0:   3 Milliseconds
```

**Block #2**

```
myFlag = 1:   3 Milliseconds
myFlag = 0:   3 Milliseconds
```

But one important thing i noticed here(thanks to [Matthew Steeples answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741033/does-if-perform-better-than-if-else/7764909#7764909)) is that since the block of code that i have tested has not used the variables height and width except for assignment in the if-else and if blocks of Code Block-1 and 2 respectively, **the compiler has optimized the IL code by completely removing the if and if-else blocks in question thus showing invalid results for our test here**.

*I have updated both the code blocks to write the values of both height and width to a file thus using them again and forcing the compiler to run our test blocks(I hope), but you can observe from the code that the actual file writing part does not effect our test results*

This is the updated results, C# and IL Code

**Results**

**Block #1**

```
myFlag = 1:   1688 Milliseconds
myFlag = 0:   1664 Milliseconds
```

**Block #2**

```
myFlag = 1:   1700 Milliseconds
myFlag = 0:   1677 Milliseconds
```

**C#.net Code**

**Block #1**

```
    public long WithIfAndElse(int myFlag)
    {
        Stopwatch myTimer = new Stopwatch();
        string someString = "";
        myTimer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            string height;
            string width;
            if (myFlag == 1)
            {
                height = "60%";
                width = "60%";
            }
            else
            {
                height = "80%";
                width = "80%";
            }
            someString = "Height: " + height + Environment.NewLine + "Width: " + width;
        }
        myTimer.Stop();
        File.WriteAllText("testifelse.txt", someString);
        return myTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

**Block #2**

```
    public long WithOnlyIf(int myFlag)
    {
         Stopwatch myTimer = new Stopwatch();
        string someString = "";
        myTimer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            string height = "80%";
            string width = "80%";
            if (myFlag == 1)
            {
                height = "60%";
                width = "60%";
            }
            someString = "Height: " + height + Environment.NewLine + "Width: " + width;
        }
        myTimer.Stop();
        File.WriteAllText("testif.txt", someString);
        return myTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

**IL Code Generated By ildasm.exe**

**Block #1**

```
.method public hidebysig instance int64  WithIfAndElse(int32 myFlag) cil managed
{
  // Code size       144 (0x90)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] class [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch myTimer,
           [1] string someString,
           [2] int32 i,
           [3] string height,
           [4] string width,
           [5] string[] CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldstr      ""
  IL_000b:  stloc.1
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
  IL_000d:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Start()
  IL_0012:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0013:  stloc.2
  IL_0014:  br.s       IL_0070
  IL_0016:  ldarg.1
  IL_0017:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0018:  bne.un.s   IL_0029
  IL_001a:  ldstr      "60%"
  IL_001f:  stloc.3
  IL_0020:  ldstr      "60%"
  IL_0025:  stloc.s    width
  IL_0027:  br.s       IL_0036
  IL_0029:  ldstr      "80%"
  IL_002e:  stloc.3
  IL_002f:  ldstr      "80%"
  IL_0034:  stloc.s    width
  IL_0036:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0037:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.String
  IL_003c:  stloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_003e:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0040:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0041:  ldstr      "Height: "
  IL_0046:  stelem.ref
  IL_0047:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0049:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_004a:  ldloc.3
  IL_004b:  stelem.ref
  IL_004c:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_004e:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_004f:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_NewLine()
  IL_0054:  stelem.ref
  IL_0055:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0057:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0058:  ldstr      "Width: "
  IL_005d:  stelem.ref
  IL_005e:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0060:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0061:  ldloc.s    width
  IL_0063:  stelem.ref
  IL_0064:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0066:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string[])
  IL_006b:  stloc.1
  IL_006c:  ldloc.2
  IL_006d:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_006e:  add
  IL_006f:  stloc.2
  IL_0070:  ldloc.2
  IL_0071:  ldc.i4     0xf4240
  IL_0076:  blt.s      IL_0016
  IL_0078:  ldloc.0
  IL_0079:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Stop()
  IL_007e:  ldstr      "testifelse.txt"
  IL_0083:  ldloc.1
  IL_0084:  call       void [mscorlib]System.IO.File::WriteAllText(string,
                                                                   string)
  IL_0089:  ldloc.0
  IL_008a:  callvirt   instance int64 [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::get_ElapsedMilliseconds()
  IL_008f:  ret
} // end of method frmResearch::WithIfAndElse
```

**Block #2**

```
.method public hidebysig instance int64  WithOnlyIf(int32 myFlag) cil managed
{
  // Code size       142 (0x8e)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] class [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch myTimer,
           [1] string someString,
           [2] int32 i,
           [3] string height,
           [4] string width,
           [5] string[] CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldstr      ""
  IL_000b:  stloc.1
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
  IL_000d:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Start()
  IL_0012:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0013:  stloc.2
  IL_0014:  br.s       IL_006e
  IL_0016:  ldstr      "80%"
  IL_001b:  stloc.3
  IL_001c:  ldstr      "80%"
  IL_0021:  stloc.s    width
  IL_0023:  ldarg.1
  IL_0024:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0025:  bne.un.s   IL_0034
  IL_0027:  ldstr      "60%"
  IL_002c:  stloc.3
  IL_002d:  ldstr      "60%"
  IL_0032:  stloc.s    width
  IL_0034:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0035:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.String
  IL_003a:  stloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_003c:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_003e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_003f:  ldstr      "Height: "
  IL_0044:  stelem.ref
  IL_0045:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0047:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0048:  ldloc.3
  IL_0049:  stelem.ref
  IL_004a:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_004c:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_004d:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_NewLine()
  IL_0052:  stelem.ref
  IL_0053:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0055:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0056:  ldstr      "Width: "
  IL_005b:  stelem.ref
  IL_005c:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_005e:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_005f:  ldloc.s    width
  IL_0061:  stelem.ref
  IL_0062:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0064:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string[])
  IL_0069:  stloc.1
  IL_006a:  ldloc.2
  IL_006b:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_006c:  add
  IL_006d:  stloc.2
  IL_006e:  ldloc.2
  IL_006f:  ldc.i4     0xf4240
  IL_0074:  blt.s      IL_0016
  IL_0076:  ldloc.0
  IL_0077:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Stop()
  IL_007c:  ldstr      "testif.txt"
  IL_0081:  ldloc.1
  IL_0082:  call       void [mscorlib]System.IO.File::WriteAllText(string,
                                                                   string)
  IL_0087:  ldloc.0
  IL_0088:  callvirt   instance int64 [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::get_ElapsedMilliseconds()
  IL_008d:  ret
} // end of method frmResearch::WithOnlyIf
```

So we can say that the **IF-Else block(Block #1) runs faster than the if block(Block #2)** as pointed by many in this forum.

Comment: Try it..? The first one is a lot more readable

Comment: the compiler might optimise the first one to the second one anyway...

Comment: The second one ends up assigning height and width twice in one case.

Comment: I know that in C++ the second might be faster if the if statement fails frequently because the compiler would place the assignments into the "stall" after the if statement. Not sure about C#.

Comment: great, i had an answer typed up, went to submit and the question was closed.

Comment: The first person to profile both code samples, posting numbers, would in my opinion get the accepted answer to this non-ambiguous, non-vague, complete, specifically tailored question that genuinely wants an answer, and which can be reasonably answered in its current form. In other words: stop closing useful questions.

Comment: @IanBoyd - Agreed, Or perhaps there might be something interesting to say about the IL they get compiled into.

Comment: also mention the type/scope of the flag. sometimes a volatile is needed there otherwise optimization may kill you.

Comment: alas, if *statements* are such a bane once you taste if *expressions*. in F#: `let height,width = if myFlag = 1 then "60%","60%" else "80%","80%"`

Comment: @MartinSmith I posted the IL code as a separate answer, thought it would help the discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741033/does-if-perform-better-then-if-else/7750404#7750404

Comment: (based on the edit about Release builds) It was not pointless, you learned how to figure this out for yourself and got a better idea of how compilers deal with micro-optimizations for you. You have tools you can use forever to figure this out quickly in the future.

Comment: @IanBoyd This site is not a place to ask for people to do that kind of work. 'profile both code samples' -- really!

Comment: Bah, i already voted to reopen this question the first time it was closed; i can't vote to reopen it this time it was closed. @bmargulies: This site is a place to ask for people to do that kind of work. '*profile both code samples*' -- really!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

### Test Results

10,000,000 iterations of **Block 1**

```
myFlag = 0:    23.8ns per iteration
myFlag = 1:    23.8ns per iteration
```

10,000,000 iterations of **Block 2**

```
myFlag = 0:    23.8ns per iteration
myFlag = 1:    46.8ns per iteration
```

**Block 2** is 96% slower than **Block 1**. Makes sense, since **Block 2** does twice the work in the pessimistic case.

> i prefer either case, depending on the situation. If `myFlag` is *rarely ever* 1, then it want it to stand out as the edge case that we have to handle. If both are equally likely, i want the `if-else` syntax. But that's preference, not fact.

---

Decades ago, the intel 80286 dual pipeline would stall if a conditional jump was taken, rather than falling through to the next instruction. By the time of the Pentium that went away; the CPU pre-fetches both branch paths. But in the back of my mind i still have a twinge of fear whenever i write code that has the most common outcome in the `else` clause. Every time i have to remind myself that it doesn't matter anymore.

---

```
Int32 reps = 10000000;

private void Block1(int myFlag)
{
    String width;
    String height;

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
    {
        if (myFlag == 1)
        {
            width = String.Format("{0:g}%", 60);
            height = String.Format("{0:g}%", 60);
        }
        else
        {
            width = String.Format("{0:g}%", 80);
            height = String.Format("{0:g}%", 80);
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Double time = (Double)sw.Elapsed.Ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency * 1000000000.0 / reps;
    MessageBox.Show(time.ToString() + " ns");
}

private void Block2(int myFlag)
{
    String width;
    String height;

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
    {
        width = String.Format("{0:g}%", 80);
        height = String.Format("{0:g}%", 80);
        if (myFlag == 1)
        {
            width = String.Format("{0:g}%", 60);
            height = String.Format("{0:g}%", 60);
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Double time = (Double)sw.Elapsed.Ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency * 1000000000.0 / reps;
    MessageBox.Show(time.ToString() + " ns");
}
```

- `String.Format` makes `IF` 96% slower
- `GetPercentageString(0.60)` makes `IF` 96% slower

---

```
const
   reps = 10000000;

procedure Block1(myflag: Integer);
var
   width, height: string;
   i: Integer;
   t1, t2: Int64;
   time: Extended;
   freq: Int64;
begin
   QueryPerformanceCounter(t1);
   for i := 1 to reps do
   begin
      if myFlag = 1 then
      begin
         width := '60%';
         height := '60%';
      end
      else
      begin
         width := '80%';
         height := '80%';
      end;
   end;
   QueryPerformanceCounter(t2);
   QueryPerformanceFrequency(freq);

   time := (t2-t1) / freq * 1000000000 / reps;
   ShowMessage(FloatToStr(time)+ 'ns');
end;

procedure Block2(myflag: Integer);
var
   width, height: string;
   i: Integer;
   t1, t2: Int64;
   time: Extended;
   freq: Int64;
begin
   QueryPerformanceCounter(t1);
   for i := 1 to reps do
   begin
      width := '80%';
      height := '80%';
      if myFlag = 1 then
      begin
         width := '60%';
         height := '60%';
      end;
   end;
   QueryPerformanceCounter(t2);
   QueryPerformanceFrequency(freq);

   time := (t2-t1) / freq * 1000000000 / reps;
   ShowMessage(FloatToStr(time)+ 'ns');
end;
```

---

Doing twice the amount of work takes roughly twice the amount of time.

Answer: IF does not perform better than IF-ELSE.

---

[image]

Comment: +1 for considering the burden of 1 extra assignment. Though we have advanced cpus, but we dont have them always everywhere. There are processors still running at 20MHz and everything makes sense there.

Comment: @abhinav: 20MHz is still **20 MILLION** operations per second.  Even in that case, this is a pre-optimization, so unless this is a *known* performance bottleneck, it's not worth the time it takes to think about it.

Comment: Don't bother to save battery power on my handheld when you don't have it. It's a free optimization that costs nothing to do. Granted, it would be useful if the compiler optimized the identical code blocks to the better case.

Comment: I did my timing which is different than yours (fixed).

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter The timing difference comes from the quirk in the OP's sample code that no extra `string` instances are needed. If the code is fiddled to ensure that a string creation is always done, then **Block 2** does twice the amount of work as **Block 1**. And since not all languages perform string equivalence like C#, it's a good general take-away from the exercise.

Comment: @IanBoyd and i was thinking the whole time that the block 2 would perform better, eye-opener. I will do the test my self and post the results

Comment: I'd be interested in how - string s = myFlag ? "80%" : "60%"; - performed; not so interested to try it out myself though :(

Comment: This benchmark should be taken carefully. Any benchmark that runs for less than a second may have results that depend more on side effects than the actual computation performance.

Comment: Vamsi Krishna answer below is far more accurate and shows a difference of 5%-15% between the two blocks.

Comment: Can you post the actual (fiddled) code you were testing here as it is clearly different from what the questioner asked.

Comment: @Ian I think it is best to leave out string declaration and include only string assignement because declaring a string is big burden that can affect the if and if-else performance we want to measure.

Comment: @MartinSmith: You could do `height = MakeCSSPercentage(0.6)` or `height = String.Format("{0:g}%", 60)` or `height = width/GetGoldenRatio()`  The point is to examine the question asked, "*Does IF perform better then IF-ELSE?*"

Comment: @IanBoyd Can you please confirm that these results were for the release build.

Comment: @IanBoyd seeing your screenshot, i guess your values are from the Debug build, can you please change the Build Configuration to Release and test the values, as I have observed that in release configuration the framework has optimized both the blocks to the same IL code(i am using Visual Studio 2010 professional)

Comment: The difference here is the runtime generation of strings.  The compiler can optimize the hard-coded "80%" and "60%", but it doesn't know what side-effects calling a function will have, so it has to call it.

Answer (score 45):

The performance gain here is negligible to the tune I'd call this micro-micro-micro-optimization. Go for readability here unless you plan to do this a couple of million times.

**Edit:** (re: question in comments)

In my opinion the first one is the more readable. It explicitly shows in a ready format what the strings should be for each case. The second one omits a case, so a reviewer would have to look through other areas of the code to determine the default value. To put it into perspective, imagine 50 lines of code between the original declaration/initialization and this particular code block. If it becomes unclear in that case then that would decide it for me.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I figured by the time I hit save there would 50 identical answers anyway :)

Comment: @Joel Can you give your opinion on which of them is more readable, b'coz i see mixed answers in the forum

Comment: "micro-micro-micro-optimization" Hmmm, "atto-optimization"? :P

Comment: Who would put 50 lines of code between the declaration and initialization of the variables?  Personally, if the intent is that you have a set of defaults, then a single condition that changes the defaults, I like the second because it communicates that intent better.  If the cases are equally likely, i.e., there are two different modes neither of which is a "default", then the first example is better.

Comment: @BoltClock Technically it's only *milli-micro* optimization, since the difference between the two is on the order of tens of nanoseconds (i.e. milli-microsecond)

Answer (score 13):

**Updated**

After updating the code according to [Matthew Steeples answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741033/does-if-perform-better-than-if-else/7764909#7764909) and testing the code in Release build according to [Lou Franco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741033/does-if-perform-better-than-if-else/7741115#7741115), i found that the If-Else blcoks perfrom better than the if block although marginally

I used the following code blocks in my test application

**C#.net Code**

**Block #1**

```
    public long WithIfAndElse(int myFlag)
    {
        Stopwatch myTimer = new Stopwatch();
        string someString = "";
        myTimer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            string height;
            string width;
            if (myFlag == 1)
            {
                height = "60%";
                width = "60%";
            }
            else
            {
                height = "80%";
                width = "80%";
            }
            someString = "Height: " + height + Environment.NewLine + "Width: " + width;
        }
        myTimer.Stop();
        File.WriteAllText("testifelse.txt", someString);
        return myTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

**Block #2**

```
    public long WithOnlyIf(int myFlag)
    {
        Stopwatch myTimer = new Stopwatch();
        string someString = "";
        myTimer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            string height = "80%";
            string width = "80%";
            if (myFlag == 1)
            {
                height = "60%";
                width = "60%";
            }
            someString = "Height: " + height + Environment.NewLine + "Width: " + width;
        }
        myTimer.Stop();
        File.WriteAllText("testif.txt", someString);
        return myTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

> The following are the results for Release build

**Results for 1000000 Iterations**

**Block #1**

```
myFlag = 1:   1688 Milliseconds
myFlag = 0:   1664 Milliseconds
```

**Block #2**

```
myFlag = 1:   1700 Milliseconds
myFlag = 0:   1677 Milliseconds
```

**IL Code Generated By ildasm.exe**

**Block #1**

```
.method public hidebysig instance int64  WithIfAndElse(int32 myFlag) cil managed
{
  // Code size       144 (0x90)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] class [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch myTimer,
           [1] string someString,
           [2] int32 i,
           [3] string height,
           [4] string width,
           [5] string[] CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldstr      ""
  IL_000b:  stloc.1
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
  IL_000d:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Start()
  IL_0012:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0013:  stloc.2
  IL_0014:  br.s       IL_0070
  IL_0016:  ldarg.1
  IL_0017:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0018:  bne.un.s   IL_0029
  IL_001a:  ldstr      "60%"
  IL_001f:  stloc.3
  IL_0020:  ldstr      "60%"
  IL_0025:  stloc.s    width
  IL_0027:  br.s       IL_0036
  IL_0029:  ldstr      "80%"
  IL_002e:  stloc.3
  IL_002f:  ldstr      "80%"
  IL_0034:  stloc.s    width
  IL_0036:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0037:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.String
  IL_003c:  stloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_003e:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0040:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0041:  ldstr      "Height: "
  IL_0046:  stelem.ref
  IL_0047:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0049:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_004a:  ldloc.3
  IL_004b:  stelem.ref
  IL_004c:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_004e:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_004f:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_NewLine()
  IL_0054:  stelem.ref
  IL_0055:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0057:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0058:  ldstr      "Width: "
  IL_005d:  stelem.ref
  IL_005e:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0060:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0061:  ldloc.s    width
  IL_0063:  stelem.ref
  IL_0064:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0066:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string[])
  IL_006b:  stloc.1
  IL_006c:  ldloc.2
  IL_006d:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_006e:  add
  IL_006f:  stloc.2
  IL_0070:  ldloc.2
  IL_0071:  ldc.i4     0xf4240
  IL_0076:  blt.s      IL_0016
  IL_0078:  ldloc.0
  IL_0079:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Stop()
  IL_007e:  ldstr      "testifelse.txt"
  IL_0083:  ldloc.1
  IL_0084:  call       void [mscorlib]System.IO.File::WriteAllText(string,
                                                                   string)
  IL_0089:  ldloc.0
  IL_008a:  callvirt   instance int64 [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::get_ElapsedMilliseconds()
  IL_008f:  ret
} // end of method frmResearch::WithIfAndElse
```

**Block #2**

```
.method public hidebysig instance int64  WithOnlyIf(int32 myFlag) cil managed
{
  // Code size       142 (0x8e)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] class [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch myTimer,
           [1] string someString,
           [2] int32 i,
           [3] string height,
           [4] string width,
           [5] string[] CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldstr      ""
  IL_000b:  stloc.1
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
  IL_000d:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Start()
  IL_0012:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0013:  stloc.2
  IL_0014:  br.s       IL_006e
  IL_0016:  ldstr      "80%"
  IL_001b:  stloc.3
  IL_001c:  ldstr      "80%"
  IL_0021:  stloc.s    width
  IL_0023:  ldarg.1
  IL_0024:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0025:  bne.un.s   IL_0034
  IL_0027:  ldstr      "60%"
  IL_002c:  stloc.3
  IL_002d:  ldstr      "60%"
  IL_0032:  stloc.s    width
  IL_0034:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0035:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.String
  IL_003a:  stloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_003c:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_003e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_003f:  ldstr      "Height: "
  IL_0044:  stelem.ref
  IL_0045:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0047:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0048:  ldloc.3
  IL_0049:  stelem.ref
  IL_004a:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_004c:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_004d:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Environment::get_NewLine()
  IL_0052:  stelem.ref
  IL_0053:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0055:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0056:  ldstr      "Width: "
  IL_005b:  stelem.ref
  IL_005c:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_005e:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_005f:  ldloc.s    width
  IL_0061:  stelem.ref
  IL_0062:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_0064:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string[])
  IL_0069:  stloc.1
  IL_006a:  ldloc.2
  IL_006b:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_006c:  add
  IL_006d:  stloc.2
  IL_006e:  ldloc.2
  IL_006f:  ldc.i4     0xf4240
  IL_0074:  blt.s      IL_0016
  IL_0076:  ldloc.0
  IL_0077:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Stop()
  IL_007c:  ldstr      "testif.txt"
  IL_0081:  ldloc.1
  IL_0082:  call       void [mscorlib]System.IO.File::WriteAllText(string,
                                                                   string)
  IL_0087:  ldloc.0
  IL_0088:  callvirt   instance int64 [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::get_ElapsedMilliseconds()
  IL_008d:  ret
} // end of method frmResearch::WithOnlyIf
```

Comment: Did you try it with a release build?

Answer (score 11):

You can answer this question yourself with a performance analyzer or just timing it (put the function in a loop that you call many times).  For all you know, the compiler turns this into the same code (you can check)

Probably you shouldn't worry about these kinds of micro-optimizations.  Write the most readable code until your tools tell you what to optimize.

Comment: France, I did as you said and posted my answer, hope it helps the community http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741033/does-if-perform-better-then-if-else/7750404#7750404

Answer (score 5):

As said before performance isn't likely to be an issue here, if you're interested in readability though you might want to try something like:

```
string height = StdHeight;
string width = StdWidth;
if (restrictDimensionsFlag)
{
    height = RestrictedHeight;
    width = RestrictedWidth;
}
```

and define your std and restricted sizes as consts or readonlys elsewhere (or read in from config).

Answer (score 3):

Correcting the result. I did my own test and I found this value which I think is more accurate. No of iterations : 100,000,000

Flag = 1

[image]

Flag = 0 .

[image]

The fact that the worse case time should be twice the best case is wrong.

The code that was used

```
string height;
string width;
int myFlag = 1;

Console.WriteLine(" ----------- case 1 ---------------");
DateTime Start = DateTime.Now;
for (int Lp = 0; Lp < 100000000; Lp++)
{

    if (myFlag == 1)
    {
        height = "60%";
        width = "60%";
    }
    else
    {
        height = "80%";
        width = "80%";
    }          

}

TimeSpan Elapsed = DateTime.Now - Start;
Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed: {0} ms",Elapsed.Milliseconds);

Console.WriteLine(" ----------- case 2 ---------------");

DateTime Start2 = DateTime.Now;
for (int Lp = 0; Lp < 100000000; Lp++)
{

    height = "80%";
    width = "80%";

    if (myFlag == 1)
    {
        height = "60%";
        width = "60%";
    }
}

    Elapsed = DateTime.Now - Start2;
    Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed: {0} ms", Elapsed.Milliseconds);
```

Comment: does the compiler figure out that `myFlag` = `1` at compile-time, and optimize away the check? If so, perhaps you should set `myFlag` at runtime (using the system clock or PRNG).

Comment: I think it does not optimize it. The condition is the same for both cases anyways. The test focuses specifically on if and if-else timing.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter Can you please confirm these are values from the release build of your test application, please see my update question for more

Comment: It was in Active mode. change it to release mode and the result are about the same. Flag-0: 406/421, Flag-1:406/453. The do vary a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning:** It's been a while since I worked with specific CPU optimizations.

That said, if I were to code this in assembly language, Block 1 would have fewer instructions per loop than block 2.  At the assembly/machine code level, if/else is essentially free when compared to if, because either case expands to essentially the same instructions (load, compare, conditional-jump).

Block1:  best case: 5, worst: 6

```
Load value of myFlag
Compare to const 1
Jump if zero (equal)  :t1
  height = "80%";
  width = "80%";
  Jump :t2
:t1
  height = "60%";
  width = "60%";
:t2
```

Block2: best case: 6, worst: 7

```
height = "80%";
width = "80%";
Load value of myFlag
Compare to const 1
Jump if non-zero (not-equal)  :t1
  height = "60%";
  width = "60%";
:t1
```

**Caveats:**

- Not all instructions are created equal, and jumps in particular tended to be more expensive when I was studying assembly... modern processors have basically done away with this tendency.
- Modern compilers do a HUGE amount of optimization, and may change the structure of your code from either one of these constructs to the equivalent of the other, or a completely different method entirely. (I've seen some rather creative use of array indices that could be used in cases like this as well)

**Conclusion:** In general, the difference, even at the machine code level will be quite minimal between these two flows.  Chose the one that works best for you, and let the compiler figure out the best way to optimize it.  All relatively minor cases like this should more or less be treated that way.  Macro-optimizations which change the number of computations for example, or reduce expensive function calls should be aggressively implemented.  Minor loop optimizations like this are unlikely to make a real difference in practice, especially after the compiler is through with it.

Answer (score 2):

The faster way to do this is probably treat height and width as ints/floats and cast them to strings at the last second ... assuming you're doing this operation frequently enough to remotely matter (hint: you're not).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the IL I think you've got a bigger problem than which if statement is quicker. Because your methods have no side effects the compiler is actually removing the contents of the if statements entirely in debug mode, and removing the if statements entirely in release mode.

Opening up the .exe file in something like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) will verify this.

You'll have to start again with something that takes a known and constant amount of time before finding out the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **Block #2**. The performance hit is negligible, as you said, but it's definitely shorter and easier to read. Essentially, you are setting default values to your variables unless a specific condition is met.

Comment: This will create garbage, if `if statement` will became true.

Comment: @VMAtm: And what is "garbish"?

Answer (score 0):

Block #2 is more readable.  However, does your company have coding standards?  If so, I would following them as much as possible or suggest consistent improvements.

As per performance in Block #1 height and width are initialized with null values, but then assigned anyway (regardless of condition).  Near zero performance difference.

Also, did you check the IL with ILDASM?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the Block #2 method just because I know the variables in question are initially set to their defaults